# yaml: why isn't this creating a subobject?

Tags: javascript, yaml, codemirror

> http://nodeca.github.io/js-yaml/#yaml=cGFyZW50OgoJY2hpbGQxOiAiZmFsc2UiCgljaGlsZDI6IAoJCXN1YmNoaWxkOiAidHJ1ZSI=

my YAML, I expect `child2` with an object containing `subchild` but it created a separate sibling field following `child2`.

```
parent:
    child1: "false"
    child2: 
        subchild: "true"
```

what is wrong with my YAML?

I expected

```
{ parent: null, child1: 'false', child2: { subchild: 'true' } }
```

but got

```
{ parent: null, child1: 'false', child2: null, subchild: 'true' }
```

Comment: Why would you expect `child2: {}` and not expect `parent: { child2: {}}`?

Comment: thats what I expected, I was focusing on the area of the problem.

Comment: I think it's due to using `tab` characters for spacing (I don't know the exact details): http://nodeca.github.io/js-yaml/#yaml=cGFyZW50OgogICAgY2hpbGQxOiAidHJ1ZSIKICAgIGNoaWxkMjogCiAgICAgICAgc3ViY2hpbGQxOiAidHJ1ZSIKICAgIA== (here it is with four `tab`s: http://nodeca.github.io/js-yaml/#yaml=cGFyZW50OgoJY2hpbGQxOiAiZmFsc2UiCgljaGlsZDI6IAogICAgICAgICAgICBzdWJjaGlsZDogInRydWUi) EDIT: Actually, I think it's because the editor pane is enforcing spaces, even if you hit `tab`. Something like that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using tabs for indentation and that is not allowed, and confuses that online parser. [Without tabs](http://nodeca.github.io/js-yaml/#yaml=cGFyZW50OgogICAgY2hpbGQxOiAiZmFsc2UiCiAgICBjaGlsZDI6IAogICAgICAgIHN1YmNoaWxkOiAidHJ1ZSI=) it looks the same and works as expected.

Answer (score 0):

Use a different YAML parser - your .yml is fine

http://yaml-online-parser.appspot.com/

Comment: omg lol that is sending an ajax request each time to parse it on the server side, that is too much